# How is/was continental drift monitored?

Tags: geology, plate-tectonics, tectonics

I am curious about current technology but I am particularly interested in what techniques were employed prior to the advent of satellite technology.

Comment: The correct term is "plate tectonics", by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scientific [GPS](http://www.pocketgpsworld.com/howgpsworks.php) and [SLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_laser_ranging) have been used for [some time](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2003JB002944/full) now, and the [measurements](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/97JB00514/pdf) are rather accurate. Not only do we measure horizontal movements of tectonic plates, but also uplift as e.g. in the Tibetan and Colorado plateaus.

Before the GPS was introduced, [paleomagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleomagnetism) were used in some studies to estimate the velocities; The age of oceanic crust are estimated by various methods and the travel distance is estimated from the width of the magnetic polarized bands in the ocean floor. To understand [paleogeography](http://www.scotese.com/earth.htm) and make good models we need to incorporate all branches of geology. E.g. [fossil records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biostratigraphy), paleomagnetism, [radiometric age estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometric_dating) of rocks.

Some active faults (E.g. San Andreas) can also be directly measured with laser ranging or, in some cases, with a measurement tape to measure deformation of trenches or railway tracks.

Still, scientists are trying to understand the exact driving forces behind plate tectonics. [Modelling](http://www.earthbyte.org/Resources/Pdf/Ghosh-Holt-2012-Science-PlateMotionsStressesGlobalDynamicModels.pdf) of [mantel dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_convection) is an interesting field of research and many questions remains.